# Search elements by tag name in an HTML folder which is inside your directory

Tags: html, vba, excel, excel-2010

As you can see, this is a code excerpt that loads an HTML document and then simply gets the element by searching them with the use of the tag name.

```
'STATEMENT_1
LoadPage IE, "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?" & _
                      "action=getcompany&CIK=" & Ticker & "&type=" & InfoType & _
                      "&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=20"

        'STATEMENT_2
        Set els = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")
```

However what about when you **do not** need to make use of the `Internet Explorer` to fetch an `HTML` document and you have the `HTML` inside your directory?

For example if i have the `HTML` document in the directory `C:\vsti` how can i point `VBA` to go/fetch from this location?

Comment: I haven't tried if it works but does changing your code's URL to local path works? (replace **"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?" & _
                      "action=getcompany&CIK=" & Ticker & "&type=" & InfoType & _
                      "&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=20"** with **"C:\vsti\yourhtmlname.html"**)

Comment: Ohhhh that could do the trick!!!1

Comment: That would still require the use of IE :-)

Comment: @Portland Runner Hah I am not sure if it will works, also I am guessing by not using IE, Codo is referring to the use of a browser opening a webpage online, but that's just my guess!  Thanks for pointing out thou

Comment: No it does not work the `Internet Explorer` opens the `HTML File` which has financial information and all hell breaks loose :P

Comment: Portland Runner has saved the day with an answer below~

Comment: Alex maybe... Not sure what "All Hell Breaks Loose" implies.  @Codo could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to use IE to interact with a local file.

**HTML File** *(Saved to desktop)*

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <Title>My Example</Title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <div class="find-me">
    You Found Me
  </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

**Excel VBA** *(with three methods shown)*

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer

    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    ' You can coment Next line To see page load
    IE.Visible = False

    'Set URL to local file
    IE.Navigate2 "C:\Users\PortlandRunner\Desktop\index.html"

    ' Wait while IE loading...  Probably don't need this since it's local
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    'Option A
    Dim foundA As String
    foundA = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("find-me")(0).innerText
    MsgBox foundA

    'Option B
    Dim foundB As Variant
    Set foundB = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("find-me")
    MsgBox foundB(0).textContent

    'Option C
    Dim tag
    Dim tags As Object
    Set tags = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("*")

    For Each tag In tags
        If tag.className = "find-me" Then
            MsgBox tag.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next tag

    'Show IE
    'IE.Visible = True

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Results:

[image]

Tested on IE10 & Excel 2010